# Conexion Oracle and ODBC

Tags: database, oracle, odbc

I need to connect the ODBC of windows 10 to an Oracle database located on an external server and I have not found documentation about it, someone knows if it is possible to make this connection and how it is done, to do this I have the server's IP Port and database name

Comment: Open the ODBC Administrator (`odbcad32`) and add the connection there.

Comment: At the time of opening the ODBC32, the user and server description request the data source but it does not appear to perform connection tests and also to place the password, do you have any documentation to make the connection?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1188

Comment: The documentation says how to install the oracle ODBC but does not say how to connect to an external database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuring an Oracle ODBC Data Source Name**
 (look this : https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/enterprise-analyzer/ea405/EA/GUID-1D791A6B-4B9F-457D-B617-A441E0362082.html )

> In the Windows Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools. The
>   Administrative tools window opens. Double-click Data Sources (ODBC).
>   The ODBC Data Source Administrator window opens. Select the System DSN
>   tab and click Add. The Create New Data Source dialog opens. Select an
>   appropriate Oracle driver and click Finish. The Oracle ODBC Driver
>   Configuration window opens. Specify the following information in the
>   Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration window: In the Data Source Name
>   field, enter a name of your choice to identify the data source. If
>   your DBA has supplied a common DSN for use across the enterprise,
>   enter it here. In the Description field, enter an optional description
>   for the data source. In the TNS Service Name drop-down, select the TNS
>   Service Name for the database in which your workspace repositories
>   will be stored. If no choices are shown, or if you are unsure which
>   name to select, contact your DBA. In the User ID field, enter the
>   database user ID supplied by your DBA. Click Test Connection. The
>   Oracle ODBC Driver Connect window opens. In the Oracle ODBC Driver
>   Connect window the Service Name and User ID fields are prefilled with
>   the information you supplied in the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration
>   window. Enter the password for your user ID and click OK. You are
>   notified that the connection was created successfully. Click OK. Note:
>   If you receive an error, verify the driver configuration settings and
>   retest the connection. See your DBA if the problem persists. Click OK
>   to exit the Driver Configuration window. Then click OK again to exit
>   the ODBC Data Source Administrator window.